# De Morgan's laws with yacc

Tags: parsing, logic, yacc

A have a simple grammar written in yacc, which builds a tree from logical expressions, consisting of subexpressions, and AND (&&), OR (||), and NOT (!) operators. I will not provide the grammar itself here, because there is nothing special about it and it is similar to countless YACC tutorial examples.

However, I need to parse these logical expressions so that all the parentheses are expanded for NOT operator according to De Morgan's laws. For example, I need to treat expression

```
!( ( A && B ) || C ) )
```

as

```
( !A || !B ) && !C
```

Is it possible to implement this by modifying existing yacc grammar?

Comment: May you meant Murphy laws with yacc :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this in YACC's reduction action for the **not** (!) operator, while building ASTs.   You can write any code you want in the semantic action.  Instead of "blindly" assembling the tree node for **not** from its child (the usual code you'd find in such a reduction action), you could write code that inspected the child to see if had had the shape required, and if so, construct the de Morgan equivalent tree of each. The code to do this a bit messy because it has to climb up and down the tree, matching nodes and rearraning subtrees, but its just yuck and not bad. Note that De Morgan's law arguably applies to children shaped both like ( A && B ) || C ) and ( A || B && C)), so  you two major subcases to handle.

I agree with Len; you wouldn't normally do this in the parser.  Its purpose is to get you set up for more complicated activities, and unless DeMorganizing is the only purpose, you'll need other code to process the AST in various was after parsing is complete, so why not leave all the processing until there?

Following that idea, my [recent SO answer on eliminating configured-dead code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10411631/120163) simplifies symbolic boolean logic; it shows one way to transform boolean logic ASTs using pattern-matching source-to-source transformations. This approach avoids yucky tree inspecting/hacking code.   It should be obvious how to write *readable* transforms that implement de morgans' law with that technique (and in fact we have done son in the past).

Comment: Oops, I forgot that yacc is a bottom up parser, so I did not consider transforming child nodes on receiving NOT token. Now the solution is trivial. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you should do in the yacc grammar itself; you should post-process the AST your grammar constructs to perform such reductions.

Your grammar *should* be producing an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of some sort—you want to walk the structure and look for something which matches the shape of `!((A && B)|| C)` and convert it in-place to `(!A || !B) && C`.

If you want more guidance with this, it may be useful to add more information or ask more questions.

**Edit**: you *should* provide your grammar if you want any aid with this at all. This sounds like a homework exercise, so I hope that's not your only reason for not providing code. Help us help you. We don't know what you're doing in the actions of your grammar, so how can we guess as to what we can do for you?